# Rewrite a system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system of differential equations:

$$x(t)'' + a  \cdot  x(t)' = j(t)$$
$$j(t)' = -b   \cdot j(t) -  x(t)' + u(t)$$

The task is: Substitute $v(t) = x(t)'$  into the system and rewrite the system as 3 coupled linear
differential equations of the same form (with
$y(t) = x(t)$ the solution sought), with the time-dependent vector function $x(t)=(x(t), v(t), j(t))$.

Write down the system matrix $A$, and the vectors $b$ and $d$ explicitly.

Anyone can guide me on how to write 3 equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to reduce the order of the first equation. If $v=x'$, then $v'=x''$ and the first equation can be written as the system $$v'=j-av$$ $$x'=v$$ so adding $j'=-bj-v+u$, you get a system in the form $X'=AX+b$, where $X=(x,v,j)^T$ and $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0 &-a&1\\0 & -1&-b\end{bmatrix}$$ and $b=(0,0,u)^T$.

I omitted the time variable, because every function here depends on it, so there's no confusion and I couldn't figure out what $d$ was supposed to be.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
&x(t)'' + a  \cdot  x(t)' = j(t)\\
&j(t)' = -b   \cdot j(t) -  x(t)' + u(t)
\end{align}
$$

Putting $v(t) = x(t)'$ we have
$$\begin{align}
v-x'&=0\\
v' + a  v - j&=0\\
j' +b j + v - u&=0
\end{align}
$$
that is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x'\\
v'\\
j'
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0& 1& 0\\
0 & -a& 1\\
0 &-1 &-b
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
v\\
j
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
u
\end{bmatrix}
$$